# Make child view slide down when added to LinearLayout

Tags: android

When inserting a child into a LinearLayout (at the top), I would like it to either slide down, or grow once it has been added.  The catch is, **I would like to slide down the existing children at the same time**.

Here is my code right now -- The animation looks ok, but when the button is added to the LinearLayout, it immediately allocates the space it will be occupying on the view, making all the children snap down rather than slide down.

```
linearlayout.addView(newview, 0);

Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.0);
anim.setDuration(800);
newview.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Did you try adding your view with "visibility" `GONE` and start your animation by setting visibility to `VISIBLE` & start the animation then? Had something similar with FadeOut/In animations before.

Comment: That has the same effect... thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to use a "LayoutAnimation" that works on the Layout itself?